# Suppressing git EOL conversion for PDFs

Tags: git, newlines

I'm maintaining a git repository of PDFs, and I'm having trouble stopping gitr converting EOLs from CRLF to LF. As the repo is shared between a Linux and Windows, and contains Linux scripts, I've opted to standardise on LF for line endings.

This is reporoot/.gitattributes:

```
*.exe -text
*.pdf -text
* text eol=lf
```

This is the (relevant?) part of reporoot/.git.config:

```
[core]
    autocrlf = false
```

The pdfs are in /Reports

When committing (on Linux), I get this message:

> warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in Reports/2017-09-22.pdf. The
>   file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

But when I pull (on Windows), the pdf is corrupt and doesn't display properly (sometimes -- I guess those that work don't have CRLFs in their data).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From the git manual:

> When more than one pattern matches the path, a later line overrides an
>   earlier line. This overriding is done per attribute.

As a result, the `* text` line is overriding the earlier lines.

The correct order for `.gitattributes` is this:

```
* text eol=lf
*.exe binary 
*.pdf binary
```